# "gobject-2.0" not found error occured running ./waf configure

Tags: python, gcc, mingw, msys, gobject

I am trying to compile libsoy using mingw and msys on windows. 
But when I run python ./waf configure , I get "checking for gobject-2.0 >= 2.32: not found". I am using the gcc compiler.

Comment: Any luck on finding the solution?